# Processing text in C with strtok encounters error at EOF

Tags: c

I tried to process a text file with C, reading each line and splitting it on delimiter "\t". The code works but outputs an additional line at the end of the file:

The test file is:

```
0 zero
0 one
0 two
```

The code:

```
void ReadClass(){
    char line[1000];
    char *ptr;
    int class;
    char word[1000];
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen("class_file", "rb");
    if (fin == NULL){
        printf("ERROR, class fine not found!");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (1){
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin);
            ptr = strtok(line, "\t");
            class = atoi(ptr);
            printf("%i ", class);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, "\t");
            //strcpy(word, ptr)   //This gives segmentation fault because of the null pointer in the end
            printf("%s", ptr);
            if (feof(fin)) break;
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

The output is:

```
0 zero
0 one
0 two
0 (null)
```

Thanks for anyone who helps.

Comment: Better loop: `while ( !feof(fin) )` instead of `while (1)` and `if (feof`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EOF` flag isn't set until you try to read from *beyond* the end of the file, which means your [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) call will read the three lines, and then after the fourth read the `EOF` flag will be set and [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returns `NULL`.

So instead of checking for `EOF` at the position you do, do it in the loop condition:

```
while (fgets(...) = NULL) { ... }
```

Comment: or move **if (feof(fin)) break;** just after **fgets()** call :)